# Connect to remote server and call API inside it with Python

Tags: python, api, ssh, apache-nifi

I want to call an API but I need to SSH to remote server and call inside it periodically. I knew that I can just create a bash script to do this with something like

```
ssh user@ip 'curl -X POST . . .. '
```

and set cron to this script to make it run periodically as I want.

But by doing this, I cannot make sure that each time that it run, cURL command that I use will success or fail. So, by using Python, I think this process is more managable which I can integrate this to make a notification alert or create a log, etc. Or integrate with my ETL pipeline (I used Apache NiFi).

My question here is that how can I SSH to remote server and call an API inside it with Python? I also need an idea to make it this be able to manage and monitor. Something like if the API call return as fail or getting the wrong result then `exit(1)`, if success, `exit(0)` which I can adapt this to NiFi processor.

Comment: Have you tried using the `ExecuteStreamCommand` or `ExecuteProcess` processors? These should allow this behavior via a script file or command like `ssh user@ip curl -X POST https://website.accessible.from.ip`?

Comment: Yeah but how can I monitor with it if it is fail?

Comment: Of course I plan to write a Python script and run with that processor

Comment: If the response code from the command is non-zero, `ExecuteStreamCommand` will route to the _non-zero status_ response, which you can interpret as "failure". More details [available here](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteStreamCommand/index.html).

Comment: Isn't HTTP response status codes are all non-zero? Like 200 for success, 4xx or 5xx for error?

Comment: The HTTP response status code will be, but that will be just one part of the output. I was referring to the exit code of the shell command, as per your question above. To determine if the curl request was successful, the next processor will have to parse the flowfile content for the status code.

Comment: @Jamiewp, if groovy scripting acceptable - possible to use ExecuteGroovyScript with library https://github.com/aestasit/sshoogr to execute remote ssh commands